# How to change the display refresh rate of an android device

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, screen, kernel

I am creating a custom ROM for my android device (MT6577 + ICS 4.0.4).The base ROM I'm using is the stock ROM of the device. My device's display refresh rate is pre-configured at 30Hz. Now, I want to change the screen refresh rate to 60Hz (I'm sure my device supports 60Hz) in my custom ROM.

I've searched around the net and found that may be passing the display parameters as command-line arguments would do the trick, but I'm not very familiar with android kernel.

Requesting you to please guide me towards right direction... any website, any thread or your own answer.

FYI:

- I have kernel code for the device with me.
- My custom ROM is working fine at 30Hz(no issues)

Thanks!

Comment: ICS and above is enabled to run at 60fps (under the graphics subsystem, within the bowels of EGL layer) unlike GB and earlier versions which gave the impression that re-drawing was *slow*. BTW, you cannot explicitly tell it to run at a certain frequency i.e Hertz for refreshes as that is non-existant! The graphics subsystem was re-designed to take advantage of the newer EGL drivers thus appears very slick and smooth when drawing on screen...